# XYToPoint PlugIn

Tags: qgis-plugins

Please is there any limited to the number of records (rows) and or attribute columns as I am trying to assign  X & Y coordinates to a DB table but unfortunately it is not displaying anything on the map? - XYToPoints PlugIn seems to work fine with a smaller table, which has less columns and rows.

Comment: ...there are probably better ways to go about doing this if you have more data than this plugin was designed to handle...

Comment: I am open to suggestions, the issue I have is that data that I need to access resides in an MS access database table and I need to be able to regularly i.e daily update the table with new records with X & Y data.

I am new to QGIS and shall struggling with it.

Comment: so is the plugin adding X,Y to your MSAccess Tables directly?

Comment: It seems that QGIS is the reverse of Esri where XY is more stable as CSV than database... it looks like the key is to export the table to comma delimited text and add as such.. http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/01/29/importing-a-dbf-containing-x-y-values-into-qgis/ is just one example of many saying fairly much the same thing.

Comment: In response to your question the PlugIn is not adding to the Db table, that has been taken care of elsewhere. 

What need to be able to do, is either be able to update the table on opening QGIS to reflect the changes i.e. additional records in the table, without going through the process of importing the table, adding the X & Y coordinate information, then re-formatting / restyling the layer each time I make any changes to the table.


The XYToPoint Plug-In would appear to do this for me, in addition to having the option to refresh all the layers. But it doesn't work for all of my DB tables.